# Reprint options list

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, break

I'm learning c++ and currently working through the practice problems in the book 'Jumping into c++'.

My current problem is that I'm trying to create a list that lets the user select an option and if the input is not one of the options it reprints the list.

I've gotten to a point where the user can select from one of the options and the program will proceed, however I can't get the list to reprint if the user input isn't one of the options.

```
{
   string option;


   while (true)
    {
    cout << "Please select and option from the following:" << '\n';
    cout << "Fish" << '\n' << "Chips" << '\n' << "Peas" << '\n';
    cin >> option;
    {
        if (option == "Fish" || option == "chips" || option == "Peas")
        {
            cout << "Thank you, you have chosen " << option << '\n';
        }
        break;
        cout << "Please choose again" << '\n';
    }

  }

}
```

I hope you can see what I'm trying to achieve here. I'm a mega noob so this really is way out of my comfort zone however simple it may appear to some of you lol.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Jess.

Comment: Because you `break` regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 2):

The `break;` command exits the current loop. Your current code executes it unconditionally, which is probably not what you intended. Move it into the block controlled by the `if`:

```
while (true)
{
  cout << "Please select and option from the following:" << '\n';
  cout << "Fish" << '\n' << "Chips" << '\n' << "Peas" << '\n';
  cin >> option;
  {
    if (option == "Fish" || option == "chips" || option == "Peas")
    {
      cout << "Thank you, you have chosen " << option << '\n';
      break;
    }
    cout << "Please choose again" << '\n';
  }
}
```

I also suggest you get rid of the nested brace block which does absolutely nothing for the program execution (you don't even have any nested variables in it):

```
while (true)
{
  cout << "Please select and option from the following:" << '\n';
  cout << "Fish" << '\n' << "Chips" << '\n' << "Peas" << '\n';
  cin >> option;
  if (option == "Fish" || option == "chips" || option == "Peas")
  {
    cout << "Thank you, you have chosen " << option << '\n';
    break;
  }
  cout << "Please choose again" << '\n';
}
```

---

Problems such as this are generally solved quickly by stepping through the code in a debugger. That's an essential skill for any programmer, and you should learn it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that, I'm using x-code. There's a debugger in that, right? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jessie-May Yes, there's probably a debugging interface in there; but I've never used X-Code, so I can't provide more info.

Comment: Just stepping through it _on paper_ would be an order of magnitude improvement to your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You issue `break` regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

`break;` needs to be inside your if statement.  Otherwise you are always ending your while loop.

Comment: Thanks, so once I've moved break to my if statement, how do I get the list to reprint?
If I now enter something random like 'potato' it'll say 'please choose again' which is great, but doesn't reprint the list.
P.S sorry if this is all horribly obvious stuff, as I say, I'm very new to this.

Comment: This list will automatically reprint if you do not enter the if statement.

Comment: Got it, it's working now! I had a weird thing going on that was printing '11db' in blue - I deleted the code and pasted it again and it would.

Thanks, all!